# Closehandle() not terminating the process

Tags: windows, winapi, process, msdn

The process is not getting terminated after closing its handle in `CloseHandle()`.

Well I have a process created by `CreateProcess()` api. Even after closing Its handle it is still running.

From the msdn, they say that `CloseHandle()` closes the handle and doesn't terminate process. Have to call terminate thread for that. Then why `CloseHandle()`?

But when I checked `CloseHandle()`'s return value, it succeeded. If so I want know what is actually done in this `CloseHandle()` and why it returns successfully. And I want to know what all operation can be done on the process using its handle. I felt misleading, as `CloseHandle()` succeeds but the process still runs on!

Would also be great what actually contains in the handle of a process and is there any differences with other type of handles? (file,I/O etc)

Comment: By way of analogy, closing a file handle does not delete the file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Why does closing the handle not terminate the process? Have to call `TerminateProcess` for that.

Closing the handle does not terminate the process because it would be absurd. Processes generally run independently of each other. If closing the process handle terminated the corresponding process, this wouldn't be the case since when a program exits, all open handles it holds are closed. Which would for example mean that if Explorer crashed, *every program you started* would be instantly terminated. That would be a desaster, and thus closing the process handle does, by design, not terminate the program.

Terminating a process is almost always a very bad idea. The same goes for terminating a thread. Never do that if you can avoid it. If you want a thread/process to exit, send it a message and wait until it has *exited* (on its own behalf). This guarantees that data is properly saved and in a consistent state, no resources are leaked, and that no serious conflicts can occur (such as a thread being terminated while it holds a lock).
Terminating threads is often troublesome, and sometimes catastrophic. The same goes for terminating processes. It is only "allowable" to terminate a process or a thread when it is caught in an infinite loop and non-responsive.

### Then why do you have to close the handle anyway, and why are you getting one at all if you must close it?

You can do certain things with a handle, among these are for example `ReadProcessMemory`, `WriteProcessMemory`,  `CancelIoEx`, running a debugger, use PSAPI, and a few others. Also you can wait on the handle, it will be signalled when the process exits. That is a very simple way of inter-process synchronization.
On the other hand, the operating system cannot release resources as long as you hold the handle open and thus have a "legitimate right" to access these. How can you for example wait for a process, if the process (or at least its structures) does not exist at all any more?

This (and the fact that the handle itself is a resource) is why you should close the handle as soon as possible *if you don't need it*. Holding it indefinitely requires the OS to keep resources around that are not needed but cannot be freed.
Closing the handle tells the operating system that *you don't need it any more*, so whenever the OS wants to release all resources associated with the process, it can do so.

### What is contained in the process handle?

Like all handles, the process handle is merely an opaque integer that doesn't contain anything. It is an index in a kernel-owned table, technically a `void*`, but that is only an implementation detail. The actual kernel structure that it refers to is not something you can directly access, not in an easy way anyway.

Answer (score 5):

A handle is a reference to some kernel-managed, reference-counted object. Normally, closing the last handle to an object will result in the destruction of such an object.

***But***: processes and threads are not killed when closing the last handle, you can think that they "start living on their own" after being started. Without this exception, you couldn't have a process outlive its parent, since each process' handles is closed automatically at process termination (and having a thread outlive its parent would require needless complications).

Anyway, all of this is documented: if you read the [documentation of CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you would have found:

> Closing a thread handle does not terminate the associated thread or
>   remove the thread object. Closing a process handle does not terminate
>   the associated process or remove the process object. To remove a
>   thread object, you must terminate the thread, then close all handles
>   to the thread. For more information, see Terminating a Thread. To
>   remove a process object, you must terminate the process, then close
>   all handles to the process. For more information, see Terminating a
>   Process.

Answer (score 2):

What you described is behavior by design. A process runs on its own, it might have zero or more handles opened, which let their holders control the process in certain ways. Once you hold a handle, you are responsible for closing it.

Termination of the process is a different thing, and you basically are not expected to terminate externally: you never know where exactly you stop the process. You are expected to somehow signal that you want the process termination, so that the process could figure it out and terminate its activity internally, and gracefully.